# Async waterfall returning 'Callback was already called'

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I understand why I get this error, however I have no idea how to fix this. This is what my first function looks like:

All I am doing is doing a get request for all of my urls which are stored in the database, and then for each URL response, I go through the body and save the values information by calling `saveInformation(value)` or `saveInfoTwo(value)`

```
function getUrlInfo(urls, callback) {
    urls.map(function(url) {
        request.get(urls, {
            timeout: 1500
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {console.log(error);
            } else {
                parseString(body, function(error, result) {
                    if (error) {console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        result.Values.forEach(function(listValues) {
                            listValues.forEach(function(value) {
                                saveInformation(value);
                            });
                            saveInfoTwo(value);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            callback(null);
        });
    });
}
```

My async waterfall looks like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    getUrls,
    getUrlInfo
], function(err, result) {
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Where `getUrls` is just a method that looks for all the urls and adds them to the `urls` array, so that `getUrlInfo` can use it.

```
function getUrls(callback) {
    var urls = [];
    urlSchema.find(function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(result) {
            clusters.push(result.url);
        });
        callback(null, urls);
    });
}
```

I use mongodb as my database.

**This works great when there is only one url. As soon as I add another url, I get this error:**

```
Error: Callback was already called.
```

Now, after trying to debug, it seems like everything works fine for the first url, and then when the second url finishes going through its foreach loops, the error is thrown.

How can I fix this?

I am pretty sure that the callback in my `getUrlInfo()` waits for all of the urls and foreach loops to finish, then continues? - which is not the case I guess.

Any help would be appreciated!

To summarise: How can I prevent the error appearing when I add another url?

Comment: Well, don't use `urls.map` which is a loop that *will* call `callback` multiple times?

Comment: Instead, use `async.map(urls, …, callback)`

Comment: Can you please show us `getUrls`? It probably calls its callback more than once.

Comment: Would you mind showing me async.map with example with my code please? I am new to callbacks. @Gil Z, updating answer now

Answer (score 0):

Your map call the function for the first URL, when it finishes, the `callback` is called. When the second one is executed, when it finishes, it will call `callback` again, thus you are having this error.

The solution, wait for all urls to finish and then call the callback.

As @Bergi said on the comments you can use [async map](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map)

```
function getUrlInfo(urls, callback) {
    async.map(urls, function(url, cb) {
      //do what you must
      cb();
    }, callback);
}
```